# Envelope / rectangle box with 'x' through it appears on various web pages in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, browser, html, css

This has been ongoing for months, and I've Googled and tried a ton of different things but cannot for the life of me figure it out.  It ONLY happens in Chrome, so when it does happen I'll just switch to Opera for that URL.

Here's an example:

http://www.developintelligence.com

And a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here's another example:

https://flippa.com

And its screenshot:

[image: Flippa]

(Notice where the comma should be after "websites")

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Press F12, switch to the console tab, and reload the page. Does anything show up?

Comment: @CyberJacob - just "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (32)" for clicktale.net, but that happens in other browsers too.

Comment: sounds like the server hosting the images from that page (clicktale.net) is refusing to send them to you. Switch to the network tab and see if you can get the URL of the image?

Comment: @CyberJacob it's definitely not an image thing, look at the question marks in the paragraph at the top; those are just in plain HTML.  I'm thinking it's some advanced Chrome setting maybe.

Comment: @CyberJacob I added another example from Flippa.  This time instead of a question mark it can't display a comma lol.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the network tab after trying to load a page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35511/discussion-between-kane-and-cyberjacob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have a solution from the current version of chrome.
[Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7thU28UqdDw) suggested that the solution was to use [chrome canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) (the dev preview version of chrome). That solution worked for me. hopefully it works for you as well.

Comment: That worked!  One bad thing is it doesn't pull in your extensions or bookmarks from the previous Chrome, but I guess that's not the end of the world.  Thanks!